# DataTable set a value for null valued data

Tags: c#, datatable

I have the following code.

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["Records"];
DataTable SelectedRows = null;

if (somecondition) {
  if (dt.Select("HoursWorked <> ContractHours").Length > 0)
  {
     SelectedRows = dt.Select("HoursWorked <> ContractHours").CopyToDataTable();
  }
}
```

**Problem:** The current code doesn't pick rows which "HoursWorked" are null.

**Requirement:** How can set something like ISNULL(HoursWorked, 0) for rows where ContractHours > 0 (preferably without a foreach)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have exactly the Function ISNULL available to build your expression. See [DataColumn.Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-5.0) docs:

So if I understand your requirements you should write:

```
if (somecondition) 
{
  string expression = @"HoursWorked <> ContractHours OR (
                        ISNULL(HoursWorked, -1) = -1 AND ContractHours > 0)";

  DataRow[] rows = dt.Select(expression);
  if (rows.Length > 0)
  {
     SelectedRows = rows.CopyToDataTable();
  }
}
```

Notice that I have sligthly improved your code calling the Select just one time, also I have changed the replacememt value for ISNULL to -1 because I think that zero is a legitimate value for HoursWorked

Answer (score 0):

You could ask for `is not null` like `var selected = table.Select("HoursWorked is not null AND HoursWorked <> ContractHours");`

Comment: Thanks, but this will pick all HoursWorked columns where value is null, but I should only pick if corresponding contrctHour > 0.